# Match only exact matches to dplyr matches() helper function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the `matches()` helper function as part of an argument to `select()` in the `dplyr` function.

The function looks like this for a hypothetical `df` data frame:

```
select(df, variable_1_name, matches("variable_2_name"))
```

At least as I'm currently using it, `variable_2_name` must be passed as a string to `select()`.

However, if there is another variable in `df` that matches `"variable_2_name"`, such as `"variable_2_name_recode"`, then `matches()` will match both of those variables. Is it possible to match only exact matches with a `dplyr` function, or with a different approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can of course just do the following when a string is not required:

```
select(df, variable_1_name, variable_2_name)
```

`matches` takes a pattern so you can try

```
# '^' anchors the match at the beginning of the string and
# '$' anchors the match at the end of the string.
select(df, variable_1_name, matches("^variable_2_name$"))
```

this should just match `variable_2_name` exactly.

If you have a function doing the select based on a string for the column name you could do the following (as mentioned by Psidom in a comment).  The first example is simpler and the second is more of what you are looking for.

```
### Example 1
### Given function and the 'df' with the column 'variable_2_name'
my_func <- function(df, colname) { df %>% select_(colname) }
my_func(df, 'variable_2_name') # Call with column name string

### Example 2
### Using one column name that is not a string with a string column name string.
### 'df' has columns 'variable_1_name' and 'variable_2_name'
my_func <- function(df, colname) {
    df %>% select_(quote(variable_1_name), colname)
}
### Call with column name returns 2 columns of data
### 'variable_1_name' and 'variable_2_name'
my_func(df, 'variable_2_name')
```

**Edit**

`dplyr::select_` is now deprecated, but the code above should be changeable to use `dplyr::select` instead of `dplyr::select_`.

Comment: Could you remind me what the ^ and $ characters do in this case?

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg I added a comment to the code.  Let me know if it needs more clarification.

Comment: Thanks. The potential problem with the `my_func` example is if there is another column that is just a string (not quoted).

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear what the ^ and $ characters do. Are those regex characters?

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg Yes, they are regex characters. They anchor the match at the beginning ('^') and end ('$') of the match string so '^var' matches 'variable' but not 'avariable'. Whereas 'var' will match 'avariable'.  For the `my_func` example, you can do what MrFlick suggested and use quote.  I will update the example.

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg Another way to look at it is if you have '$abc' this essentially means "begins with 'abc'" (followed by anything or nothing).

Comment: @steveb, you meant '^abc' right, not '$abc'. ^ is for begins and $ is for ends there.

Comment: @ShanR You are correct, `^abc` is what I intended to say. Thanks for catching that. I wish SO would allow me to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just one quoted variable and one string, I'd probably use the standard evaluation version and not bother with `matches()`

```
dd<-data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, aa=1:3)
dd %>% select_(quote(b), "a")
```

Since `b` isn't a string, we need to `quote()` it in this case. Or just use a string for b as well

```
myvar <- "a"
dd %>% select_("b", myvar)
```

Comment: I forget about `quote`, I am glad you added it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`one_of`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_helpers.html) helper from dplyr:

```
select(df, variable_1_name, one_of("variable_2_name"))
```

As desired, this only selects columns that are an exact match, avoids potential problems if your column name includes regexp characters (e.g. `.`), and doesn't rely on the [deprecated `select_`](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/). It's also nice that it works even if the string-valued column name is stored in a variable:

```
# still works when the column name is stored in a variable `v`
v <- "variable_2_name"
select(df, variable_1_name, one_of(v))
```